# How to catch this exception in java and log it

Tags: java

```
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.qwest.www.webserv.DslwsWSPortStub.getBroadbandCustomerInfo(DslwsWSPortStub.java:243)
    at com.qwest.www.webserv.DslwsWSPortProxy.getBroadbandCustomerInfo(DslwsWSPortProxy.java:51)
    at com.qwest.acs.webservices.DSLWebService.getDSLWFCustomerInfo(DSLWebService.java:181)
    at com.qwest.acs.test.DSLWSTest.main(DSLWSTest.java:111)
```

Comment: You'll have to show the code you used there. From the current point, all we can do is guess and I'm quite a bad psychic.

Comment: `catch (AxisFault e) { doSomething(); }`?

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(SocketTimeoutException e){//do}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  /* your code that's throwing the exception goes here. */
} catch (AxisFault af) {
  /* your logging code goes here. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At Line 111 of

```
DSLWSTest.java
```

throw in a

```
 try {
     // existing code causing the exception
 }
 catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex) {
    // log exception
 }
```

Comment: Not sure about this one since the socket timeout here seems to be a _wrapped_ exception. But I don't use Axis, so...